# Markers of a line plot are cut off or how to adjust the left and right margins in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axes, margins

I have a code to produce the following chart. as you can see, the circle markers are cut off in the left and right area of my chart.
[image: pic1][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfW70.png)

my code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
%matplotlib notebook
plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6), facecolor='w', edgecolor='blue')

my_colors=['orangered','seagreen', 'goldenrod', 'springgreen', 'sienna']

ax.set_ylim(-0.7, 33)  

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(reset=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))


ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

x_axis = ax.axes.get_xaxis()
x_label = x_axis.get_label()
x_label.set_visible(False)
ax.set_ylabel('Points won', color='darkblue',  fontdict={'fontsize': 14, 'fontweight': 'medium'})



ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=12, bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=False,
               left=False, right=False, labelright=False)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelcolor='black', width=3,color='black', labelsize=14, bottom=True, top=False, labelbottom=True, labelrotation=90,
               left=False, right=False, labelright=False)

ax=merged.plot(y=['Kinver Con Club', 'Nomads', 'Plough', "Gaters 'A'", 'Alveley Oaks'],marker='o',figsize=(9,6),legend=None, color=my_colors, ax=ax)

selectcols=merged[['Kinver Con Club', 'Nomads', 'Plough', "Gaters 'A'", 'Alveley Oaks']]

for line, name in zip(ax.lines, selectcols.columns):

    y = line.get_ydata()[-1]
    ax.annotate(name, xy=(0.99,y), xytext=(6,0), color=line.get_color(), 
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                size=16, va="center")

merged.plot(y='Footloose', marker='o', figsize=(9,6), legend=None, color= 'steelblue', ax=ax, alpha=1,
                    transform=mtrans.offset_copy(ax.transData, fig=fig, x=0.0, y=4, units='points'))   

y = 12
ax.annotate('Footloose', xy=(0.99,y), xytext=(6,0), color='steelblue', 
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                size=16, va="center")

merged.plot(y=['Top Pub'], marker='o', figsize=(9,6), legend=None, color= 'darkred', ax=ax, alpha=1,
                    transform=mtrans.offset_copy(ax.transData, fig=fig, x=0.0, y=3*(1), units='points'))      
y = 22
ax.annotate('Top Pub', xy=(0.99,y), xytext=(6,0), color='darkred', 
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                size=16, va="center")

y = 16
merged.plot(y='Alveley Royals', marker='o', figsize=(9,6), legend=None, color= 'darkviolet', ax=ax, alpha=1,
                    transform=mtrans.offset_copy(ax.transData, fig=fig, x=0.0, y=-1.8, units='points'))  
ax.annotate('Alveley Royals', xy=(0.99,y), xytext=(6,0), color='darkviolet', 
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                size=16, va="center")


# Adjusting the size of the plot to fit the team labels

fig.subplots_adjust(left=.075, right=.72, bottom=0.15, top=.90)

# Horizontal grid lines
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter('{:.0f}'.format))
ax.grid(True, 'major', 'y', ls='--', lw=.6, c='darkgray', alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

I have tried to use this line to change the chart area yet it does not solve my problem.

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=.075, right=.72, bottom=0.15, top=.90)
```

some lines in this are offset, eg. for 'Footloose','Top Pub' and 'Alveley Royals'.. I can change x = 0.0 to x = -4.8, to fix these three (see picture 2). yet I am not sure how to adjust all of them.
[image: pic 2]

Comment: Did you try setting the margins?  By default they should be 5%, but perhaps your style file overrides this:  `ax.margins(x=0.05)`

Comment: nope.. tried both plt.margins(x=0.05) and ax.margins(x=0.05), it does not make anydifference.

Comment: Well, I can't test your code to see what the issue is because its not self-contained, nor particularly minimal.  Suggest you strip stuff out until it isn't broken anymore, and then you will have found the problem.

Comment: could the issue be the position of the ticks?